# Is it correct/common to say "a cosmetic" as opposed to "cosmetics"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

> Mary's lips were blood-red. Was it the result of her genes or **good
>   cosmetics/a good cosmetic?**

My senses tell me that it should be "a cosmetic". However, a Google [search](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22or%20a%20*cosmetic.%22&rlz=1C1ASUC_enTW628TW628&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq88i_wNPXAhVBUZQKHX7rAd8Q_AUIDygA&biw=1920&bih=974) that cosmetic is often paired with another words (e.g. cosmetic results), in short, being used as a verb.

Comment: All the examples in your Google books search use *cosmetic* as an adjective. Also, have you checked a dictionary? I suspect you will find your answer there.

Comment: @Laurel Even the dictionary uses "cosmetics" (noun) instead of "cosmetic" (noun) in its examples: https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=cosmetic+define&rlz=1C1ASUC_enTW628TW628&oq=cosmetic+define&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2956j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on what Mary used. Did she use lip gloss, lipstick and liner? If so, good cosmetics may have something to do with it. If she used just lipstick, then it was a good cosmetic indeed.

There is also the general sense. 
If Mary's appearance may, in general, be cosmetically enhanced then, yes, good cosmetics might be her secret.

Answer (score 1):

If Mary used [cosmetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmetics) to make her lips blood-red, one could be forgiven for doubting her genes. But maybe Mary had a bruised lip and needed a hide this [cosmetic](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/cosmetic) damage. Despite the fact that she doesn't usually wear lipstick, she thought it was the perfect cosmetic for the situation. Both alternatives are essentially equivalent. But there are some nuances, I think:

> Was it the result of her genes or good cosmetics?

Meaning, "good genes or good cosmetics?"

> Was it the result of her genes or a good cosmetic?

Meaning, "a good cosmetic" vs. "her (bad) genes".

There is an emphasis in "a good cosmetic" — sounds almost like an accusation. If you already knew how ugly Mary's lips were, definitely go for the singular, because you know that only **a good cosmetic** could make her lips look so good. But if you just met Mary, and she's beautiful, and you have no good reason to doubt her beauty, go with the plural.

Comment: Here, we are referring to *a* lipstick. That's why I felt a bit weird using the plural "cosmetics." Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: From the context we have no reason to exclude other cosmetics. Women use more than a lipstick to emphasize their lips. Was it a lip liner used? Is it a tattoo? If you are certain that the text excludes other cosmetics and it's just one lipstick than go for the singular. But do note that it shifts attention from her lips to "a good cosmetic". So the question is, what is the focus of the sentence, her lips or the lipstick? Context is everything.